# Unity check which object is being hovered by mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hy,

So here's the problem, i have the mouse cursor that is being moved by a controller joystick and i would like to show a message when an object of my ui is being hovered by it, a message in the console like : "Object : " + ObjectName + "got hovered !".

Also, i use the new Unity Input System if it can help in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow. You need to try something out and show your attempt with a minimal reproducible example. You can check [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry i'm new to Stack overflow so i'm a little lost on it, i'll try out what you suggested, thank you again.